# deleting a file in android emulator (AndroidStudio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, delete-file

I only want to delete a specific file in my AndroidEmulator running Android 7.1. My app created it and for testing I need to delete it again.

I am not able to do.

Any hints how I could do ?

***Update***

I guess I was to unprecise with my question. 
I do not want to do it with code, just using an App on the emulator, because it is not a standard process of my app. Its just a special testcase.

I guess I found a solution for API24, API25 : In settings under Storage I can click on used Storage and I get a kind of fileexplorer.

But with other API's I can't find a Fileexplorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
String mfileName = "/Name Folder/File.jpg";  

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+fileName;  

File f = new File(path);
Boolean deleted = f.delete();
```

Comment: Sorry, My question was not very precise. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a file, you could manually delete it from your project folder

Comment: Sorry, My question was not very precise. I have updated the question.